# Can I set the number of threads for FFMPEG on the Raspberry Pi 3 to 4 since it is a Quadcore?

Tags: pi-3, cpu, ffmpeg

I want to use the full potential of the Pi 3's Quad Core ARM. Right now my FFMPEG encoder is set to 1 Thread (settings from my Pi 2.) I'm curious if I can up the thread count to 4 since I have 4 cores to play with now.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: The thought did cross my mind. Just worried about potential damage to hardware. I can always start at two threads and work my way up.

Comment: You cannot damage hardware this way.  Running all cores at ~100% will slowly heat them up but shouldn't overheat the CPU unless you've overclocked.  Also, the Pi firmware will throttle the CPU when it's temperature hits 80℃.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have direct control over thread count.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006716/ffmpeg-is-using-more-threads-than-i-expect-when-using-threads

I want to do the opposite, limit it to one thread as a background process.  I can renice it to a lower priority but it's still running 4 threads by default.

My Pi's overheat indicator is on, it's just gonna have to throttle, but that slows every process down.  And it's a 2.4 GB file, it's going to be a long day.